# How to destroy "the other" instance in Game Maker 2.0

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

I'm using Game Maker 2.0.

I'm generating instances of an helicopter in the Control object as this:

```
if ( !global.helicopter_wait && global.num_helicopters <= global.max_helicopters )  
{
    instance_create_layer(800,200,"inst_game",obj_helicopter);
    global.num_helicopters++;
}
```

Then, in there is a missil object where I've put the following code in the Step event:

```
if ( place_meeting(x+hspeed,y+vspeed,obj_helicopter) ){
    instance_destroy();
    instance_destroy(other);
    global.num_helicopters--;
    global.score += 10;
}
```

The problem is that the missil instance is destroyed but the helicopter's one is not. Also, I've tried to do the same with the the collision event, but it does not work either.

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `instance_destroy();` (or put it as the last line of the code within the check).

```
if ( place_meeting(x+hspeed,y+vspeed,obj_helicopter) ){
    instance_destroy(other);
    global.num_helicopters--;
    global.score += 10;
    //instance_destroy(); //activate this line if you want to remove the missile as well
}
```

Once `instance_destroy();` is triggered on itself, it won't continue the code within the object past that line.

There's also a function that counts all existing objects in the current room, that could save you some trouble keeping track of the `global.num_helicopters`. For that, you could take a look at [`instance_number`](https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Asset_Management/Instances/instance_number.htm)

Comment: Thanks Steven. What you've said is totally logic. But I've tried and it still does not work. With the following code the instance destroyed is the missile one instead of the helicopter:

if ( place_meeting(x+hspeed, y+vspeed, obj_helicopter) ){
 instance_destroy(other);
 global.score += 10;
 //instance_destroy();
}

Debuging seems that the self variable and the other variable has the same ID. Is this possible?

Comment: I think it's because `place_meeting` doesn't keep track of the object it's colliding with , thus it won't be stored in the `other` variable. I know 2 solutions for this: (1) use `instance_place()` so the colliding object is stored in the variable, or (2) put the function in the "On Collision" Event where it collides with the helicopter, as that will fill up the `other` variable

Comment: The code *will* continue after the instance_destroy() call - marked-for-destruction instances are processed several times per frame between different event types (so if you destroy an instance in Step, it'll still be accessible in other objects' Step events during that frame)